# Russian verb “to meet by chance”

Tags: грамматика, словоупотребление, глаголы

I know that *случайно встречаться* и *случайно встретиться* means “to meet by chance” but I looked up the verb conjugation and I can't seem to find where they get the verb. Are the words *случайно встречаться* a whole verb by themselves?

Comment: The verb is *встречаться / встретиться*.

Comment: Well, _случайно встречаться_ is a shorter form of _встречаться от случая к случаю_; meaning more like _to meet from time to time_. I wouldn't say it's the same as _случайно встретиться_ at all.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Случайно** is an adverb, 'accidentally', and **встречаться** is a verb, 'to meet'.

Wiktionary has a [conjugation table](https://ru.wiktionary.org/wiki/%D0%B2%D1%81%D1%82%D1%80%D0%B5%D1%87%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C%D1%81%D1%8F) for it.

Answer (score 3):

Когда речь идет о случайной встрече, обычно используются глаголы:

- натолкнуться (разг.),
- наткнуться (разг.),
- пересечься (реже, но все же, кажется, возможно),
- повстречаться (обычно в сказках или литературе в общем).

Answer (score 1):

`столкнуться` is a very good one for this case.
It literally means `to bump into` or `to collide with`
So people would say: `Вчера я столкнулся с Машей в кафе` = `I bumped into Masha at the coffee shop yesterday`

Answer (score 1):

There is a *single verb* with the meaning *'to meet (somebody) by chance*': **повстречать** (кого - perfective, transitive). It is most often found in Russian fairy tales, poetry, etc.

> Шёл он, шёл и повстречал зайца.
>
> Повстречался ему медведь.